# In ASP.NET MVC app, simple custom HTTPModule issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpmodule

My first custom HTTP Module, baby step 1 - just getting the plumbing down.

I'm not getting my string in the 200 response but it is there in 304 responses. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

My class:

```
namespace WebUI.Models
{
    public class SimpleModule: IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
        }        

        void OnEndRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {            
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");           
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I'm getting for a request for a css file and there's my "rrrrrr....rrrr" at the end:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Last-Modified: Sat, 20 Feb 2010 17:20:59 GMT

Accept-Ranges: bytes

ETag: "b0d1d31151b2ca1:0"

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2010 22:57:31 GMT

rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
```

But the r's don't show in my 200 response for the page's html.

Thanks for any help,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured out why - Compression.  I took it out and now I'm getting the rrrr's in my 200 response.  Now I just have to figure out why this is so.

`//response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, compress);`